# XMLtable xmlquery

Tags: plsql

how do I extract xml document from a plsql using select xmltable passing columns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<Response xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">
<Header xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">
<MessageID xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">2600</MessageID>
<RelatesTo xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">12033428</RelatesTo>
</Header>
<Result xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">
<ResultCode xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">0</ResultCode>
<ResultMsgCode xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">Success</ResultMsgCode>
<ResultMsg xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">Success</ResultMsg>
</Result>
<Payload xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">
<SubmitShipmentResult xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">
<ReferenceNumber xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">01523</ReferenceNumber>
<DeliveryTrackingNumber xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">01753077</DeliveryTrackingNumber>
<LoggingDetails xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">
<LoggingDetail xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">
<Code xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">0</Code>
<Message xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">Message is rightly processed</Message>
</LoggingDetail>
</LoggingDetails>
<ShpUnits xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">
<ShpUnit xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">
<RefNo xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">1523_0001</RefNo>
<ExtRefNo xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">01753194</ExtRefNo>
</ShpUnit>
<ShpUnit xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">
<RefNo xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">1523_0002</RefNo>
<ExtRefNo xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">01753195</ExtRefNo>
</ShpUnit>
<ShpUnit xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">
<RefNo xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">1523_0003</RefNo>
<ExtRefNo xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">01753196</ExtRefNo>
</ShpUnit>
</ShpUnits>
</SubmitShipmentResult>
</Payload>
</Response>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

```
select xt.* 
from t_xml x, XMLtable('/Envelope/Body/Response/Payload/SubmitShipmentResult'
passing x.COL_XML
    COLUMNS "RefNumber" Varchar2(30) PATH 'ReferenceNumber',
            "DelTrackNumber" Varchar2(30) PATH 'DeliveryTrackingNumber') Xt ;
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What do you mean by "from a plsql"? PL/SQL is a coding language, it's not something you can select from? Please edit your question and clarify exactly what you're trying to do, and include any issues that you've had with it. Does your query not work?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck 
￼

Comment: Hi Nima, I have the xml response posted on top, it is stored in a clob table column. I need to select the specific elements from the xml file. elements data I am interested in are the following : <RefNo xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">1523_0002</RefNo>
<ExtRefNo xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">01753195</ExtRefNo>

Comment: I need to extract data from the following elements <RefNo xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">1523_0002</RefNo>
<ExtRefNo xmlns="http://Spv.co.za/schemas/CreateCashup/DataModel/Schema.xsd">01753195</ExtRefNo> 
to variables. I have attached the xml above. my select statement is not returning rows :  select xt.* 
from t_xml x, XMLtable('/Envelope/Body/Response/Payload/SubmitShipmentResult'
passing x.COL_XML
    COLUMNS "RefNumber" Varchar2(30) PATH 'RefN0',
            "ExtRefNo" Varchar2(30) PATH 'ExtRefNo') Xt ;